# Where's the TOOLS menu and menu bar?

Tags: tools, menu-bar

I just installed Ubuntu 13.0.4 alongside Win7 on my machine and I am a RANK beginner with Ubuntu (first day, literally). I cannot find the TOOLS menu anywhere. I have no menu bar.

I have been looking for tips online and reading some documentation, but still no luck. Advice?

Comment: About what tools menu are you talking?

Answer (score 2):

**The menu appears at the top of the screen when you move your mouse-over it.**

It is a context-specfic menu meaning that menu options available will change depending on what program/application you have open and have selected.

[image: Ubuntu global menu]

Answer (score 0):

There's no Tools menu by default on Ubuntu. It depends on what you want to do. You access most functionality by opening the Dash (press the Super or Windows key) and looking at stuff in there.

I found a tutorial that may be useful for you:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QGhx-u-c5Cg

Answer (score 0):

You should find 'System Settings' icon on the launcher which may be what you want.